# Index of within-participant consistency in two-alternative forced-choice (2AFC) task?

Tags: categorical-data, binary-data, reliability

My study consists of 2AFC trials: Participants choose which one of a pair of stimuli has a certain quality.  There are 9 pairs and 6 stimuli (2 categories of 3 stimuli each) in total.  The stimuli within the pairs are repeated across trials, contrasting the 3 stimuli from each category exhaustively as below:

> 1 vs. 4
>
> 1 vs. 5
>
> 1 vs. 6
>
> 2 vs. 4
>
> 2 vs. 5
>
> 2 vs. 6
>
> 3 vs. 4
>
> 3 vs. 5
>
> 3 vs. 6

I want to know whether people respond consistently in trials that contain the same stimuli.  For instance, for trials in which one of the stimuli was # 1, every participant has three responses; and same for all other stimuli.  I can calculate the consistency of responses in these trials within-participants in a rough way.  Assume the below responses in the first 3 trials above (with #1 as one of the pair):

> Participant 1: 1 0 1
>
> Participant 2: 0 0 0

Obviously, participant 2 is more consistent (100%) than participant 1 (66.7%).  I can compute something like this across all trials in which one of the stimuli is constant (this would create redundancy, though: 1 vs. 6 would be included in my calculation twice: Once for 1s and once for 6s).

I am looking for a more formal way to index such intra-individual variability (or within-participant consistency).  R script would be swell.  Thank you in advance.